# Using video thumbnails from windows explorer in java?

Tags: java, windows

I'm working on a university project and i'd like to know if it is possible to access and use the thumbnails on video files as seen in windows explorer using java?

Comment: who what with what for

Comment: @gpasch edited a little. My bad should be clearer now.